# Despliegue de Contenedor

Tags: laravel, git, docker, gitlab, pipeline

Con una molestia, les comento que estoy tratando de desplegar una imagen de Docker desde CI/CD de GitLab para ponerlo en un contenedor, la imagen sí existe dentro del servidor, pero a la hora de ejecutar mi pipeline genera este error, no sé si le falta alguna configuración.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La autenticación lo genera bien

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé si me falta alguna configuración en el repositorio o en el servidor(CentOS7)

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: esta claro que el problema esta en que estas usando una imagen de docker que necesita registro y el pass docker lo guarda en el sistema, el CI esta en otra maquina por lo que no esta tomando las credenciales, mejor has la imagen de docker publica para poder utilizarla en el CI, tambien puede que el server no tenga acceso a la direccion o tenga algun bloqueo ---  que hay en tu archivo ci.yml ???

Comment: El código y los mensajes de error siempre _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes.